# graph time vs frequency

Tags: audio, display, measuring

I am in search of a code which can display the real time graph. I am going to display the microphone input signal in frequency vs time domain. The function that I am expecting is same as the **vocal pitch monitor** an app in the google play store. The music notes in the y axis are different set of frequencies if some one can help me with code please.

Comment: What programming language do you have most experience? Have you started to program this allready and could add the code to your question?

Comment: hello brother , i am just a beginner in python language .if you have any suggestions on which function that suits me please do

Comment: Can you please be more specific where to display the graph?  Is it a monitor directly attachet to the raspberry or maybe a browser on a different computer accessing the raspberry?

Comment: hello bro,thank you for considering my question ,I am planning to display it in the monitor that is attached directly to the raspberry pi using the HDMI

Comment: the view i am exactly expecting is as same as pitchlab an app from playstore.

Comment: Writing a whole application will often need some hours of work even if you do know how to program and have a basic understanding how to solve it. I for one offer to copy&paste my own stuff whenever I have something that resembles whats needed. In this case there is a lot of stuff that I know only by name. You will need learn [pyAudio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39342170/406423), finding [the pitch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1797631/406423) and showing the result as a [live graph (probably with pygame)](http://www.instructables.com/id/Streaming-Data-Visualization-Plotly-Raspberry-Pi/).